# How do I make UIButtons not work

Tags: ios, uibutton, storyboard

When i press a button on my ViewController I want som other buttons not work (sounds a bit weird). I still want them to be there but just work. Please help :D

Comment: Like `otherButton.enabled = NO;`?

Comment: Take risk and read UIButton Documentation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either of this according to your situation.

> ```
> button.userInteractionEnabled = NO;// it will disable the action that is going to call
> button.enabled = NO;// it will set the button in disabled mode and you can customize it accordingly
> ```

Answer (score 1):

`[myButton setEnabled:NO]` should make the button ignore touch events AND should have some sort of visual feedback for the user (as opposed to setUserInteractionEnabled:NO alone).

To quote the docs:

> ### enabled
>
> A Boolean value that determines whether the receiver is
>   enabled.
>
> @property(nonatomic, getter=isEnabled) BOOL enabled
>
> > **Discussion**
> >
> > > Specify
> > >       YES to make the control enabled; otherwise, specify NO to make it
> > >       disabled. The default value is YES. If the enabled state is NO, the
> > >       control ignores touch events and **subclasses may draw differently**.

(Emphasis mine)

Answer (score 0):

If you also want it to be invisible and disabled  use:

```
self.button.hidden = YES;
```